# Missing TUN/TAP driver on embedded Linux

Tags: drivers, kernel-module, embedded-linux

I came a long way to encounter this problem, so several dead end steps will be omitted.

I was trying to create a TAP interface. The first step taken was to check if I have the needed tool (which I seemingly have):

```
root@analog:~# ip tuntap help
Usage: ip tuntap { add | del } [ dev PHYS_DEV ] 
          [ mode { tun | tap } ] [ user USER ] [ group GROUP ]
          [ one_queue ] [ pi ] [ vnet_hdr ] [ multi_queue ]

Where: USER  := { STRING | NUMBER }
       GROUP := { STRING | NUMBER }
```

I decided to check if I have the needed kernel module installed/compiled/inserted, and it turned out I haven't

```
root@analog:~# lsmod | grep tun
root@analog:~#
```

Installation of the module turned out to be problematic

```
root@analog:~# modprobe tun
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.6.0-ga94cfb9/modules.dep.bin'
```

Which made me question myself if everything is fine with dependencies and such

```
root@analog:~# depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-ga94cfb9: No such file or directory
```

This made the problem even more complicated since the only place I've encountered this mystical combination of symbols is

```
root@analog:~# uname -a
Linux analog 4.6.0-ga94cfb9 #5 SMP Mon Dec 12 10:50:01 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I honestly have no idea on what kind of information might be useful for solving the problem, but I beg for any ideas which could move my investigation a bit further

Comment: What distro? that your kernel has no module support smells unusual. ARM linux varients tend to be a but specialised, so what device and distro this runs would be handy.  I think your read on the problem in the answer is probably correct tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeek , [this](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/tree/altera_4.6) would be the most accurate answer I could possibly give to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More research led me to what seems to be the answer to my question.

I know for sure that some drivers are present on the device I'm having problems with, but I couldn't find them physically on the device (.o/.ko files seem to be missing somehow).

It seems like the

> drivers are compiled directly into the kernel
>
> kernel does not have module support

as was mentioned by Ulrich Dangel [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/lsmod-returns-nothing-on-my-embedded-device).

I had to set the needed driver in .config (can be done manually or using `make menuconfig`)

```
# CONFIG_TUN is not set
CONFIG_TUN=y
```

compile the kernel, and replace old `uImage`.

I checked if the needed driver runs by `dmesg | grep tun` where `tun` is the needed driver name. Now everything works perfectly